# WebPack Как исключить папку из сборки?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, apollo-client

WebPack Как исключить папку из сборки?

У меня есть изоморфное React прилжоение. На сервере оно рендерит данные из базы данных напрямую, а на клиенте должно к api запросы давать.

в мной написанной функции useQuery({}) я использую изоморфный код, примерно такой:

```js
function useQuery(){

  if(process.isBrowser){
    return require('./api')
  }

  return require('../server/api')

}
```

Вебпак при сборке клиент-версии всё ровно `../server/api` в сборку пытается пихать, вместе со всем сервером, со всеми секретными api методами, их реализацией, базой данных и.т.п.

Как мне ВООБЩЕ НАСИЛЬНО исключить все файлы которые находятся в папке server? чтобы если на клиенте и выполнится (а оно не выполнится) require('../server/api') то чтобы оно undefined возвращало?

То есть как мне вообщее НАМЕРТВО защитить папку server от попадания на клиент?

Ни exclude ни externals не работают, например если я эксплюжу и екстерналю все файлы из папки /server/** то если они внутри себя что-то импортируют из node_modules, то оно всё ровно в сборку пытается пихаться, и бывает ругается что модуль fs отсутствует, или mongodb отсутствует.

Как сделать чтобы вебпак ВООБЩЕ не анализировал папку server и при попытке запросить от туда любой файл возвращал undefined? То есть прям всё, табу, святое, секретные данные. Чтобы вебпак взорвался, но ни одного бита из папки server в клиент не пропустил. Как такое провернуть?

Answer (score 0):

Я побыстрому написал решение, кому надо юзайте =)
Кто знает лучше - скажите плиз, мне кажется должен быть какой-то более нативный способ.

```js
function excludeDir(excludedDirs = []) {

  if (typeof excludedDirs === 'string') {
    excludedDirs = [excludedDirs]
  }

  const nodePath = require('path');

  const fileInDir = (filePath, dirPath) => {
    if (dirPath === filePath) return true
    const relative = nodePath.relative(dirPath, filePath)
    return relative && !relative.startsWith('..') && !nodePath.isAbsolute(relative)
  }


  return (context, request, callback) => {
    const filePath = nodePath.resolve(context, request)

    const fileInExcludedDir = excludedDirs.some(excludedDir => {
      return fileInDir(filePath, excludedDir)
    })

    if (fileInExcludedDir) {
      return callback(null, `commonjs ${ request }`);
    }

    callback();
  }

}



// usage
webpackConfig.externals = [excludeDir('./server')]
```

Теперь все импорты `require('../server/api')` заменятся буквально на `require('../server/api')`, а по скольку у вас функции require в глобальной области видимости в браузере нет, то такие запросы  будут бросать ошибку =) что нам и нужно было. Теперь даже если вы случайно импортнете что-то, что случайно импортит что-тот из секретной папки, то это просто выбросит ошибку на клиенте =)! Ура!